# Unknown argument "record" on field of type "Mutation" (graphql-compose)

Tags: graphql

I'm confused about how to create a Resolver correctly in graphql-compose: I have two related entities : entityGroup and entity. I want to create a default entity each time an entityGroup is created: so I need to call the resolve method of **EntityGroup.createOne**, then use that result's id to call "Entity.createOne"

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
import { composeWithMongoose } from 'graphql-compose-mongoose';
import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose';

import {Resolver} from 'graphql-compose'

const customizationOptions = {}; // left it empty for simplicity, described below

const EntityTC = composeWithMongoose(Entity, customizationOptions)
const EntityGroupTC = composeWithMongoose(EntityGroup, customizationOptions)

const entityGroupCreate = new Resolver({

    name: 'entityGroupCreate',
    type: EntityGroupTC,
    args: {
        name: 'String!',
    },
    resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
        const created = await EntityGroupTC.getResolver('createOne').resolve({ source, args, context, info })
        console.log("created entity : ", created)
        return created
    }
});


schemaComposer.rootMutation().addFields({
    entityGroupCreate,
}
```

Now from the client side, I call the same code that I was using for the raw case where entityGroupCreate used the preexisiting resolver:

```
schemaComposer.rootMutation().addFields({
    entityGroupCreate: EntityGroupTC.getResolver('createOne'),
}
```

My issue is that everything works fine for the predefined resolver, but with my resolver I described above I get this error:

> graphQl error :  Unknown argument "record" on field
>   "entityGroupCreate" of type "Mutation". graphQl error :  Cannot query
>   field "recordId" on type "EntityGroup". graphQl error :  Cannot query
>   field "record" on type "EntityGroup". graphQl error :  Field
>   "entityGroupCreate" argument "name" of type "String!" is required but
>   not provided.

this is my query

```
const ADD_COMPLAINT = gql`mutation complaintCreate($entityId:String!, $title: String!, $desc: String!)
    {
    complaintCreate(record:{entityId:$entityId, title:$title, desc:$desc}){
        recordId, 
        record{
            _id, 
                entityId,
                user {
                    userId,
                    userName,
                    roleInShop
                },
                title,
                desc,
                createdAt,
                updatedAt
            }
        }
  }`
```

Now I understand that the mutation schema is wrong, but I really don't know where to start since that schema is constructed by graphql-compose-mongoose, and I touhght I can simply name it in the type field of the resolver : **type: EntityGroupTC**

I attempted to redefine the response format as specified in the comment:

```
const outputType = EntityGroupTC.constructor.schemaComposer.getOrCreateTC("entityGroupCreate", t => {
    t.addFields({
        recordId: {
            type: 'MongoID',
            description: 'Created document ID',
        },
        record: {
            type: EntityGroupTC,
            description: 'Created document',
        },
    });
});
```

but I still have these errors

> graphQl error :  Unknown argument "record" on field
>   "entityGroupCreate" of type "Mutation". graphQl error :  Field
>   "entityGroupCreate" argument "name" of type "String!" is required but
>   not provided.

So I have to understand how this part works : [https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose/blob/master/src/resolvers/createOne.js:42](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose/blob/master/src/resolvers/createOne.js)

```
args: {
      ...recordHelperArgs(tc, {
        recordTypeName: `CreateOne${tc.getTypeName()}Input`,
        removeFields: ['id', '_id'],
        isRequired: true,
        ...(opts && opts.record),
      }),
    },
```

In my opinion this is staring to get complicated for a library that is supposed to write less wiring code : I'm sure I'm doing it the wrong way...

Best regards,

Comment: I think there's a part of the answer in the file https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose/blob/master/src/resolvers/createOne.js:23-34 now the question is: should I define that again for each mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was just in front of me :/, this is the end of the day syndrom

```
const createOneResolver = EntityGroupTC.getResolver('createOne')

const entityGroupCreate = new Resolver({
    name: 'entityGroupCreate',
    type: createOneResolver.type,
    args: createOneResolver.args,
    resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
        const created = await createOneResolver.resolve({ source, args, context, info })
        console.log("created entity : ", created)
        return created
    }
});
```